# "git pull" broken

Tags: git, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to Snow Leopard and "git pull" returns:

```
rakudo $ git pull
git: 'pull' is not a git-command. See 'git --help'

Did you mean this?
        shell
rakudo $ git-pull
-bash: git-pull: command not found
```

I've tried reinstalling via macports, but to no avail.  Then I saw this

```
rakudo $ git --exec-path
/Users/ovid/libexec/git-core
```

That surprised me as that directory does not exist, nor has it ever existed.  Google is not helping here.  Hopefully you can :)

Comment: I ran into same problem, when I tried to hack git binary out of Xcode package. `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git      ~/bin/git`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking in the source of git, there's a comment in git.c:

```
/*
 * We use PATH to find git commands, but we prepend some higher
 * precedence paths: the "--exec-path" option, the GIT_EXEC_PATH
 * environment, and the $(gitexecdir) from the Makefile at build
 * time.
 */
```

If you call `git --exec-path`, you end up calling `const char *git_exec_path(void)` in [exec_cmd.c](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/exec_cmd.c#L72).  That looks like this:

```
const char *env;

if (argv_exec_path)
    return argv_exec_path;

env = getenv(EXEC_PATH_ENVIRONMENT);
if (env && *env) {
    return env;
}

return system_path(GIT_EXEC_PATH);
```

Now, _argv_exec_path_ is set when you say `--exec-path=/some/where` so can be discounted.  You've stated that the environment variable isn't set.  `GIT_EXEC_PATH` is defined during compilation in the [Makefile](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L1508).  Going backwards, it seems to be defined as just `libexec/git-core`.  So, we need to look at what [system_path()](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/exec_cmd.c#L10) does instead.

I'm not sure whether `RUNTIME_PREFIX` is defined for you.  But while nosing in the Makefile, I did notice that [prefix](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L231) defaults to `$(HOME)`.  I suspect that this may be the cause of your problems.

The simple answer is to put this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/opt/local/libexec/git-core
```

If you want to find out more about what's going on, you'll probably have to recompile git using `port -d upgrade -f git-core` (or similar) and look closely at the build log to see where prefix is being set.  Incidentally, `port cat git-core` shows heavy usage of `${prefix}` so it should (hopefully) be obvious.

Comment: Just a clarification for anyone else who finds this: the path to git's commands is indeed set at compile time (though it can be modified by GIT_EXEC_PATH, and then by --exec-path). This is most likely set at compile time by `make prefix=/path/to/git ...`. Hopefully any pre-built versions will properly do this!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps of note: Adding the export statement to ~/.profile (which exists by default in my Snow Leopard install, neither .bashrc nor .bash_profile do) also works.

Comment: I had this same problem, but on my web host. The general solution seems to be, find wherever your /libexec/git-core is, and then set GIT_EXEC_PATH to that path as described here. In my case it was in $HOME/git/src/libexec/git-core

Comment: I've got two virtually identical RedHat servers, both with git 1.7.6 compiled from source. On one, git pull works fine, on the other I get the error above. Have tried chmod a+rx /usr/local/libexec and have tried export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/local/libexec/git-core in both the user's .bashrc and .bash_profile. It does work for root, but not for user accounts. Baffled. Suggestions? I'd even be happy to recompile the source if there was a magic flag to give it.

Comment: I was finally able to fix this by installing git via yum rather than compiling. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. try `echo $GIT_EXEC_PATH`, `which git`. It's unlikely to be related to the snow beast…

Comment: $GIT_EXEC_PATH is not set and "which git" returns /opt/local/bin/git, as I'm expecting.

Comment: This is weird. I've had no problems with `git` and snow, but I don't use the macports' one. Once I get home I'll try the macports' `git` and see if it misbehaves...

Comment: And even after upgrading to the most recent version.

Answer (score 2):

On my system, `libexec/git-core` is in `/usr/local` and  not `/opt/local`.  The `/usr/local/libexec` directory had only root accessible permissions for me, and this fixed the problem:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/libexec
```

Comment: That one worked for me too.  I had installed (configure, make, sudo make install) on Mac OS X, and apparently it put the wrong permissions there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the steps on the [ports Migration wiki page](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)? It was painful, but after doing the `--force` uninstall and reinstall process, I haven't had any issues with any of my ports, which includes `git` (with pretty much every variant turned on).

Comment: Yeah, did that a couple of days ago after I found so many of my ports not working.  It was, as you mention, painful.  It also didn't solve my git problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Git compiles so easily there's really not any reason to bother with any of macports' craziness. Get rid of whatever's in /opt and try building it the normal way. Odds are good it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to download from the helpful page on GitHub:

http://help.github.com/mac-git-installation/

They have a stand-alone installer (though the second option there is MacPorts...)

They used to have a very nice all in one page tutorial that seems to be splintered now.  What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was an issue only specifically relevant to my brew install. On OSX 10.9.2, I had brew installed under root, so this works for me:

```
sudo su
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core
brew update # or whatever you want from here
```