# Gitolite git clone error

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to setup gitolite on my server (Macos server).

I followed the instructions in the INSTALL document found here :
http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/1-INSTALL.html

I installed the root method.

I got everything setup (ssh pubkey authentication and default gitolite setup)

```
$ssh git@server info
hello admin, the gitolite version here is v1.5.9.1-27-gb97115f
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W  gitolite-admin
    @R_ @W_ testing
```

According to installation instruction I should be able to checkout a repository.

But when I try to clone the gitolite-admin repositry I get an error:

```
$ git clone git@server:gitolite-admin
Cloning into gitolite-admin...
Assertion failed: (argv0_path), function system_path, file exec_cmd.c, line 27.
error: git-shell died of signal 6
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I got the latest git version of gitolite and git v. 1.7.3.4

Can anybody help me?

Edit 1: added git clone command before error message

Comment: what is the git clone command you use?

Comment: git clone git@server:gitolite-admin

Comment: I'd try cloning like this: "git clone ssh://git@server/gitolie-admin", but don't know if this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: this seems to be an improvement now i get : Cloning into gitolie-admin...
R access for gitolie-admin DENIED to user
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: which is weird, because I was supposed to have RW access

Comment: sorry, gitolite is actually misspelled here, when I run git clone ssh://git@server/gitolite-admin I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 8):

It seems the correct fix to this error is to add

```
$ENV{GIT_EXEC_PATH} = "/usr/libexec/git-core";
```

to your .gitolite.rc file.

Comment: Had the same problem. This is the simplest (and working) fix, and it makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

The [OP skipper3k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623049/skipper3k) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041067/gitolite-git-clone-error/5090221#5090221) an issue with `RUNTIME_PREFIX` in Git, a bit similar to "[`git pull` broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken)" question:

> I'm not sure whether `RUNTIME_PREFIX` is defined for you. But while nosing in the `Makefile`, I did notice that prefix defaults to `$(HOME)`. I suspect that this may be the cause of your problems.
>
> The simple answer is to put this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/opt/local/libexec/git-core
```

> If you want to find out more about what's going on, you'll probably have to **recompile git using `port -d upgrade -f git-core`** (or similar) and look closely at the build log to see where prefix is being set.
>   Incidentally, `port cat git-core` shows heavy usage of `${prefix}`.

---

Original answer:

First, did you get the most up-to-date gitolite version?
At https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/, you need to consider the '**`pu`**' branch.

The [installation documentation is then this one](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html).

---

[GitoliteV3 or 'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html) doc:

> "Installation" consists of the following options:
>
> 1. Keep the sources anywhere and use the full path to run the gitolite command.
> 2. Keep the sources anywhere and symlink just the gitolite program to some directory on your $PATH.
> 3. Copy the sources somewhere and use that path to run the gitolite command.
>
> You can run the 'install' command in 3 different ways:

```
# option 1
gitolite/install

# option 2
gitolite/install -ln
# defaults to $HOME/bin, or use a specific directory:
gitolite/install -ln /usr/local/bin

# option 3
gitolite/install -to /usr/local/gitolite/bin
```

---

Old answer for gitolite V2:
Second, I prefer the <del>"**[from-client method](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/1-INSTALL.mkd#_from_client_method_install_from_the_client_to_the_server)**"</del> method:

> The advantage of this method is that it forces you to solve the ssh pubkey problem before attempting to install.
>   It works best if you have dedicated userids,
>
> - one on the server for installing gitolite,
> - and one on the client for administering it.
>
> The disadvantage is that the admin user ends up with two keys
>
> - one for shell access (that he started with) and
> - one for gitolite access (which the script creates if needed).

So I like to create a **`~/.ssh/config`** file with the two different sets of parameters:

```
host gitolite
     user git
     hostname server
     identityfile ~/.ssh/git
host gitadmin
     user git
     hostname server
     identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa (myaccount public key)
```

The **gitolite-admin** is only visible for the first public ssh key:

```
C:\HOMEWARE\git>ssh gitolite
hello git, the gitolite version here is v1.5.9-25-ga10287a
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W      gitolite-admin
    @R_ @W_     testing
Connection to server closed.
```

With my account:

```
C:\HOMEWARE\git>ssh gitadmin
hello myaccount, the gitolite version here is v1.5.9-25-ga10287a
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
    @R_ @W_     testing
Connection to mccprdgit10 closed.
```

So:

```
C:\HOMEWARE\git>git clone gitolite:gitolite-admin
Cloning into gitolite-admin...
remote: Counting objects: 16, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
```

Comment: Tnx, I wil try out this method. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I get and error with $ssh gitadmin
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Comment: do I need any special ssh settings for gitolite ?

Comment: @skipper3k: no, just a full ssh access. What exact command do you type and what exact full error message do you get?

Comment: I've made a fresh gl-easy-install now and in the end i get this: now we will clone the gitolite-admin repo to your workstation and see if it
all hangs together.  We'll do this in your $HOME for now, and you can move
it elsewhere later if you wish to.


...press enter to continue or Ctrl-C to bail out
Cloning into gitolite-admin...
Assertion failed: (argv0_path), function system_path, file exec_cmd.c, line 27.
error: git-shell died of signal 6
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: This error message and the one you [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken) are completely unrelated. One is a problem locating the porcelain binaries, this is a nasty system configuration error from git-shell.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the way git was compiled on mac. I had to manually compile git without the RUNTIME_PREFIX set. Now it works.

Comment: How exactly did you unset RUNTIME_PREFIX? Is that the same as building without `make prefix=/bleh/bleh`?

Answer (score 2):

I pretty much tried anything I could think of and couldn't get it to work...until I noticed somewhere that GIT is very high on email addresses...so I regenerated my ssh keypair using the -C option:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "**nospam@nowhere.org**"

Low and behold, all of a sudden I could clone gitolite-admin without any problem.

Apparently the email in .gitconfig's **user.email** key **MUST correspond** to the email that was used to generate the SSH key. Honestly, if you only have 1 keypair in your .ssh folder, why on earth does it matter that the email corresponds? Imho, if you pass a key and the key is in the authorized_keys on the server, it should work regardless of the .gitconfig user.email property.

Answer (score 0):

don't know exactly which is the problem with your installation, it would be useful to know which commands you 've executed to install gitolite in your your server.

I recommend you to read these two links, they were helpful for me when I installed gitolite:

http://kris.me.uk/2010/09/30/git-repository-server-gitolite.html (specially this one)

http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html

Comment: I did the exact installation like described in the 1. link. I figure there must be something wrong with my ssh configuration ?

Comment: Maybe this is related with your problem: http://groups.google.com/group/gitolite/browse_thread/thread/937543a80c7753ed.

Are you using a shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Having just dealt with this for a *third* time after forgetting the first two times, I figure it can't be unusual.

```
$ git clone git@hugo:gitolite-admin
Cloning into gitolite-admin...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

At least one reason for this is that the gitolite user *must* have a login shell - making a system user won't work for some reason.. it just falls over, causing the error above.

Also, for the ssh test, you *must* switch off PTYs on the command line otherwise ssh simply won't work - I think maybe it worked with older versions of ssh but doesn't on anything I have:

```
$ ssh git@hugo
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

$ ssh -T git@hugo
hello key, this is git@hugo running gitolite3 v3.01-10-g699bafa on git 1.7.10
```

(why it thinks I'm called 'key' is another config issue I haven't solved yet).

Answer (score 0):

To pile on, as a solution for Gitolite v3, for Mac Lion, this is what worked for me:

> $ENV{PATH}="/usr/local/bin:$ENV{PATH}";

Add it to **~/.gitolite.rc** for the **git user on the server**. Make sure it is before the "1;" at the end.

As detailed in: https://serverfault.com/questions/307493/cant-clone-gitolite-admin

The solutions involving GIT_PATH are outdated, according to:
http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2migr.html