# Gitolite client side on Windows machine

Tags: git, configuration, netbeans, msysgit, gitolite

I am a developer and recently my company have decided to work with `Gitolite` repository.

I work on a Windows machine and I have created my private/public key using PuTTYgen and I sent my public key to repository administrator and he added me as a developer to the project.

I am using Netbeans with Git plugin installed.

My questions are: Do I need to install anything else to push my local repository to the remote server? Msysgit is necessary to be installed or not? Do I need some other configurations to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is push/pull of `git+ssh` protocol:

- **[NbGit](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/)** uses JGit, which should support that feature by now
- [Netbeans Git plugin](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_main) (Oracle) might not support yet the push feature (according to [their plan](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan))

So if you can make either one of those pugin work for push, you don't require [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (using msysgit would mean leaving Netbeans to perform Git operations).

Comment: Actually I use `Netbeans 7 RC2` so I see that `NbGit` is working only for `Netbeans 6.9`. And `Netbeans Git plugin` is not supporting push yet. So my option for now is only `msysgit`? ...This given, is there some tutorial how to config `gitolite` to work with `msysgit` on a Window machine so that I can push to remote server?

Comment: @Ek Kosmos: you mean your gitolite server is a Windows one? Anyway, there isn't much configuration on the client side (Windows - msysgit) to push to a gitolite server. The main setting to watch out for is the environment variable `HOME` (which isn't a variable defined by default in a Windows environment). This is where msysgit will look for your `~/.ssh` keys.

Comment: No, I have no server to configure. I only need to configure my local Windows machine so that when I write: `git push --all git@THESERVER:THEPROJECT` in `msysgit` to work. For this I have asked if you know some tutorial, but if you say isn't much configuration on the client side only the `HOME` variable, I will take care at that.

Comment: @Ek Kosmos: don't forget to edit your `~/.ssh/config` file (see second part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041067/gitolite-git-clone-error/5041898#5041898. That way, you can `git clone gitolite:THEPROJECT` instead of `git clone git@THESERVER:THEPROJECT`

Answer (score 1):

Gitolite is supposed to be completely transparent to both client and server operations except to mediate access.

On the client this means it's just another ssh based git URL.  Personally I hate putty/plink but I know they (can be made to) work.  Someone contributed putty.mkd to gitolite docs; you can check there.

On the server this means it's just another bare repository, except it has a special 'update' hook that you must not fiddle with.  Otherwise there's no difference.