# Gitolite - How to create users?

Tags: git, ssh, configure, gitolite, settings

I tried to install git + gitolite following [this manual](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/1-INSTALL.mkd) - using root instalation from server. 
I just do not understand if new gitolite users **have to have their user accounts?**. When I add *tester.pub* key into *keydir* folder and configure access to some repository, git always ask for a password and do not allow me to clone anything

```
git clone tester@myserver.com:testrepo
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/testuser/git/testrepo/.git/
testuser@myserver.com's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't believe that create system account (*adduser testuser*) is neccessarry because gitolite should be installable and configurable even without root access onto server.

So could anybody please show me what I have misunderstood?

Thank you very much.

---

**EDIT:**

Well... I reinstall gitolite using client instalation [transcript](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/install-transcript.mkd). Now adding and pushing new pub keys successfully changes ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for my *git* user on server. So it seems better than my first try.
But I still can not clone any repozitory from another place.
When I try to add pub key + edit config for my windows PC with msysgit, then try

```
$ git clone git@server.com:project.git
cloning into project...
Fatal ERROR: unable to authenticate
Fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

<strike>On other hand when try another linux, it still request for password.</strike>

```
# git clone git@server.com:project.git
Cloning into project...
git@server.com's password:
```

Even when I provide password for git user:

```
fatal: 'project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**This was probably caused by broaken system account.**

Now I really dont know what to do - should I create somehow .ssh/config on each client to make it work?

Now I am starting to be little bit annoyed and upset and I will probably remove all and try mercurial:-D 
Except someone could help me:) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes thats the problem... me too faced the same.. i created the public key using puttygen ssh2-rsa format gitolite does not accept this. You need to convert to openssh

> ssh-keygen -i -f yourname.pub > yourname_openssh.pub

Now use this converted public key

Comment: @macintosh264: This may mean that your key is already in the OpenSSH format.

Answer (score 3):

There is no '`keydata`' folder, only '`keydir`' and '`conf`' (as mentioned [in the documentation](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/2-admin.mkd#_adding_users_and_repos)).

If you have cloned locally the `gitolite-admin` repo (`git clone gitolite@server:gitolite-admin`), you need to:

- add your new public key named after the user in the `keydir` repo: `username.pub`
- add that same username in one of the user groups in `conf/gitolite.conf`
- push back the new modifications to the gitolite server (there is a special hook on the `gitolite-admin` repo which will add the new public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file).

Comment: Thank for your reply. I did all of these steps, but it still ask me for password. Am I suppose to edit those *hooks*?
*You have right with keydir, I wrote wrong dir name:) - corrected in question*

Comment: @Zap: no hook edits necessary ;) If it asks for any password, then the public key must have *not* been added to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file correctly. That happens when the `gitolite-admin` is pushed using the wrong account (that is one which hasn't full write right on `gitolite-admin`). What exact message do you see when pushing back a modified `gitolite-admin` repo?

Comment: I think, push works without problems. Message is
`Counting objects: 7, done.`

`Delta compression using up to 4 threads.`

`Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.`

`Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 344 bytes, done.`

`Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)`

`To git@server.com:gitolite-admin`

`   be99f7e..5892732  master -> master`


I will probably try to reinstall gitolite using another install method and see if it will help

Comment: @Zap: ok. I recommend the "from client" method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041067/gitolite-git-clone-error/5041898#5041898)

Comment: @Zap: not at this stage, considering no hook edit should be required.

Comment: Well, I made some experiments - it seems that was a problem with weird linux account - I created fresh one and it **works**. It means I can clone, commit and push from linux.
But problem with windows and msysgit still persists :-/ I copied pub key directly through my network disk to exclude mistakes, but still `Fatal ERROR: unable to authenticate` But it it will be probably problem in msysgit/SSH key gen there rather than gitolite

Comment: @Zap: did you generate your public/private key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` within a bash session, with `$HOME` correctly set?

Comment: @VonC probably. `$ echo $HOME` = /c/Users/zap. With `ssh-keygen -t rsa` keys are created in folder `C:\Users\zap\.ssh\ ` and are listed in bash using `ls ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

I solved msysgit problem.

1. I reinsall msysgit and use OPENSSH instead of PUTTY (it is recommended in install manual of gitolite - but I had msysgit installed before)
2. when generating ssh-key, it **must** have default name **id_rsa** otherwise it did not work for me

Because I always had custom name for key, I can not say if step 1 is neccessary and I won't try it again:) Now I can clone/commit/push - finally.

Special thanx to VonC for his patience