# Sourcetree on Mac connecting to Gitolite asks for authentication

Tags: gitolite

We've recently set up Gitolite server. All seems well. I can connect to it without a problem.

A new user has been set up, he's on a Mac and trying to use SourceTree. The only way I could get him to connect was for him to attempt to ssh to the server and I typed in the password (exited afterwards). Without that the system kept asking for a password for that server.

Is this normal behaviour?
How do non-sysadmin users gain access to gitolite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) is based on [forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858), which means non-interactive session.
So:

- no password should ever be entered (assuming here non-password protected private key).
  (as detailed in "[how gitolite uses ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html)").
- no "non-sysadmin" should ever gain access to gitolite server itself.

So all he should need is a public key stored in `~/.ssh` (making sure both his `home` and `.ssh` aren't group or world writable), registered in `gitolite-admin/keys` and published on the gitolite server `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

From there, as mentioned in "[Sourcetree and Gitolite](http://www.borborygmus.net/2011/11/sourcetree-and-gitolite/)":

> If you are cloning a remote git repository, you need to tab out of the Source path/ URL field to activate the clone button.
>   The url will be validated at that point.
>
> The url needs no special syntax working with gitolite, and even respects the host entries in your ssh conf  file. So in my case a url of `gitolite:workrepo` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks VonC, the "how gitolite uses ssh" is particularly useful. Somehow I thought gitolite added the keys to authorized_keys, but I see I need to do it manually.

Comment: @RogerI yes, Gitolite will add the public key automatically to the authorized_keys file, linking that key to the gitolite-shell script (at least for gitolite v3, aka g3). I would not recommend adding a key manually.

Comment: Hmmm ... I tried it again on another mac (different user). On the server her pub key seems to have been correctly added to authorised_keys, on her own machine known_hosts has an entry for the server. However, when I attempt to add the "testing" repo it still asks for a password. The pop-up window is entitled "Password Required" and beneath that "For user git on host <mygitserver.com>". The key was generated on my Mac and copied over.

Comment: @RogerI if the private key isn't protected by a password, then the public key hasn't been copied correctly to `authorized_keys` (but it should have been if done through gitolite, that is through pushing the `gitolite-admin` repo with the pub key copied in it with the right name), or it has been copied, but with the wrong name: the name of the public key must be: `yourLoginName.pub`.

Comment: I finally got it working, it required two changes: 1) removed the passphrase 2) used a config file. Is this because I generated the key with: "ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "Joe Bloggs" -f ~/.ssh/joebloggs". Perhaps if I'd allowed it to go to the default filename it would have worked?

Comment: Aha - I regenerated the key on the new Mac and didn't specify the output file. Works first time! Note to self: if one specifies the output file then use a config file.

Comment: @RogerI I confirm: no passphrase, and you can use the default filename (`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` if you are using only this set of keys), but you *need* to rename your public key when copying it to the `gitolite-admin/keydir` repo: there, the public key needs to be called `joebloggs.pub`. Again, please read http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html Everything is in it.

Comment: @RogerI example of a config file (for non-default named ssh keys): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041898/6309