# git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: macos, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“git pull” broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken)

Using `git version 1.7.5.4` on my MAC

When trying to `pull` from remote, i am getting the

`git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` error.

This used to work. Something changed on my system, not sure what.

How can this be resolved please? What might be the problem here?

Comment: We sure don't know better than you what you did to your machine. Try reinstalling git?

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you confirm that git-core is in the correct place?

```
iMac:~ david$ git --exec-path
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core
iMac:~ david$ ls /usr/local/git/libexec/
git-core
iMac:~ david$
```

Comment: I have `/usr/libexec/git-core` coming back, following by `ls: /usr/libexec/git-core: No such file or directory`. Where could my path  have been screwed up? I am using `oh-my-zsh` with `plugins=(git)` entry. This change is the only one i can think of

Comment: Do you have the same directory as me per chance? You could always create a symlink to fix the discrepancy or create a git alias that sets --exec-path.

Comment: I searched for the `git-core` and added it to path. All is ok now. Not sure what happened. Thanks man

Comment: For details on this issue, see the "possible duplicate", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken