# git: 'pull' is not a git command - CentOS VPS server

Tags: linux, git, centos, vps

I recently set up a new VPS and have installed Git via yum and wget etc. All seemed well - I can add, commit, set up a remote and push to github.

However, when I try to pull from github:

```
user@domain.com [~]# git pull github master
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    shell
```

No, I didn't mean shell, I meant pull!

Now I've googled the heck outta this - including reading several posts on Stackoverflow:

["git pull" broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken)

[git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473145/git-pull-is-not-a-git-command-see-git-help)

Although most posts seem to be about Mac issues (I'm on a CentOS server), it seems to be an issue with the git exec path, which is

```
user@domain.com [~]# git --exec-path
/usr/local/libexec/git-core
```

I've tried adding a various things to .bashrc with no success.

The key thing is that when I cd down to /usr/local/ and ls -l, I can't see a libexec directory.

But if I log in as root, I can cd to /usr/local/ and see libexec/, inside which is git-core. I can also git pull as root.

So - I suspect the problem is more to do with permissions and the server setup than git itself.

I've tried

```
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/libexec
```

But that did nowt too...

When I ssh into another server, as an account user, I can cd down to /usr/local and see libexec - so there's something wrong with this server setup.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: check how /usr/local is mounted; probably it's a dynamic overlay that is only visible for `root`. btw, i really don't think that this is a `git` problem, bbut rather a configuration problem of your system

Comment: Thanks umlaeute, I've solved it now - the server is using jailshell... Disabling jailshell and using 'normal' shell works a treat.

Comment: @user1455542 you should post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it now - the server is using jailshell... Disabling jailshell and using 'normal' shell works a treat