# Git push or pull doesn't work on remote server

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-push, git-pull

I'm following [Dan Eden's Github workflow guide](http://daneden.github.com/github-workflow/). I've come across a problem when trying to push my changes to Github from my remote, using `git push -u origin master`. I've added all the files to the stage and committed them, and when I use the command above, it returns this:

```
To git@github.com:tomoakley/5-lines.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:tomoakley/5-lines.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I try and use `git pull`, as it suggests, which returns this:

```
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    shell
```

I've contacted both my web host, who say it is not a problem with the Git install but rather a problem with my ssh keys (using `ssh -T git@github.com` returns with the normal authenticated message), so it can't be that. I also contacted Github, who are currently investigating. The Github support guy told me to use [SSH agent forwarding](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) which I'm now doing.

A few details about my server and git:

- `git --version`: git version 1.7.12
- `git --exec-path`: /usr/local/libexec/git-core

Thanks to anyone who answers :)

Comment: usually on initial push you might want to `git push -f -u origin master`

Comment: @three great, that works for the push! Still not fixed the pull though. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @three The error message he's getting when pushing suggests this is not his initial push, and he certainly shouldn't force it if the remote branch is ahead of his.

Comment: @adamdunson I'd had a couple of pushes from my local machine to test it before hand with just .txt files and stuff but nothing major. I'd removed them again before so the repo was empty when I made this push.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2717404/1095946) to a similar question suggests fixing permissions on the /usr/local/libexec directory with

```
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/libexec
```

Not sure if it will apply to your situation, though.

Another option is to add the GIT_EXEC_PATH variable to your .bashrc (add this to the bottom):

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/local/libexec/git-core
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have sudo access on my remote server. Any other way I can carry out that command without involving sudo?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Can you check to see if `git fetch` and `git merge` work?

Comment: Also, see my updated answer about the GIT_EXEC_PATH variable. You should be able to run that line directly to see if it works before adding it to your .bashrc.

Comment: git fetch and git merge appear to work, but adding export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/local/libexec/git-core to the end of my .bashrc file didn't seem to have an effect. Running it in the command line didn't do anything either.

Comment: Does `ls /usr/local/libexec/git-core` display any files? If not, you could set `GIT_EXEC_PATH` to a directory that you *can* change permissions on, and you could copy all the git executable files to it. Kind of a hack but it might work if nothing else does.

Comment: Alternatively, since `git fetch` and `git merge` work, you could create an alias to do what git pull does, e.g., `alias gitpull='git fetch && git merge FETCH_HEAD'` (this is probably a terrible solution, though).

Comment: ls /usr/local/libexec/git-core doesn't do anything (returns no such file or directory). I dug a bit deeper and libexec folder doesn't exist either. Also, if it helps, using     which git    returns /usr/local/bin/git (which does exist).

Comment: Can you run `locate git-core | grep 'git-core$'` and see if it returns anything?

Comment: locate git-core | grep 'git-core$' returns:
locate: can not open `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': Permission denied

Comment: Well then. I suppose you could try something like `find /usr -name 'git-core'`.

Comment: `find /usr -name 'git-core'` returns:
`/usr/local/share/git-core
find: /usr/local/apache/domlogs: Permission denied`

Comment: At this point, you need to send this information to your web host and let them know that git needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help. Will tell them again and hopefully this time they won't just brush it off.