# OSX Git pull - not valid

Tags: macos, git, terminal

This error probaby has something to do with my path/environment variables but I don't know enough about those to fix this issue, any help is appreciated.

```
git pull
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
apple
shell

git --exec-path
/opt/local/libexec/git-core

which git
/usr/bin/git

echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin`
```

Comment: Post the output from `git --exec-path`.

Comment: updated original question with output

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken

See if that helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Shouldn't `which git` produce `/opt/local/bin/git`? I'd say you need `/opt/local/bin`in your path in front of `/usr/bin` for all mac ports stuff to work. Try `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`.