# How to resolve git 'pull' is not a git command in Linux

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket

I have cloned the git repository in Linux server and able to run `git fetch, git status, git log` commands.

I am getting an error while i run git pull as below:

```
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        shell
```

HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ERROR.

Comment: Please, write exactly in your question what you type in the console.

Comment: May be this other answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a broken installation of Git, I'd recommend to reinstall (on Ubuntu, this would be via `sudo apt-get install git`). The `pull` command is implemented as a shell script called `git-pull` located in the path returned by `git --exec-path`. You might want to check if the file is there.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the 'pull' command isn't in your path.

Try adding the following to your .bashrc, or whatever shell you're using:

`export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/opt/local/libexec/git-core`

And if necessary, reload bash.

Answer (score 0):

for me nothing above worked.

**Solution:**

There was some bad character that was displaying as space but actually it was something else.