# Git return "'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'" from remote on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, windows-10, bonobo

I have a bonobo server on my server that is running windows 10. 
I'm trying to link a new hook on "Update", so the files from the node development server can get updated directly from git.

I tried to do so using a cmd file, examples to follow:

### update file in hooks

```
cmd //C "start C:\webServer\node\testServer\update.bat"
```

### update.bat on the same folder on testServer

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
cd C://webServer/node/testServer
git pull
```

That was returning the following error:

> git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

I did some research and found out this post ["git pull" broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-broken) where they talk about using -exec-path on Mac, I tried to search the equivalent in Windows and found out some variables for path related issues, tried them an none of them worked, also tried to reinstall git without any other result, at that point I was tired of it and I tried to use a node library, simple-git, that allows me to do a pull request using node specifying the path! I tried it on the server, and it worked! (I will attach the code of the file below) so I thought to try it from the remote server, but then I got the same error again, pull is not a git command, I tried to call the node file in different ways, I tried some python script to run a cmd command that runs the node server, I tried using bat and sh files, even using node to run another instance of node, and nothing worked, it always returns pull is not a git command :/

### Node simple-git code

```
require('simple-git')("C:\\webServer\\node\\testServer")
     .pull(function(a,b){
        console.log(a,b); //for debug
     })
```

Has additional information, git is properly set up as an environmental variable and I can access it without problems from the server, this issue only happens when trying to execute the pull from the hooks!

If anyone can give me some tips on what to try that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: about the `%PATH%` in your bat file : `%PATH%` should contain a list of *directories*, get rid of the `\git.exe` part. Is that enough to fix your bug ?

Comment: I'm afraid that I got the same error after changing it :/

Comment: Ok. To debug, I would check what user account is used when the bat script is run (`echo %USERNAME%` ? my windows is rusty) and dump some extra info on what binaries he can access (maybe the equivalent of `ls -l C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`, I don't know the options to `dir` by heart)

Comment: Or the equivalent from the node script